# MS SQL Convert date to short

Tags: sql, datetime

I am trying to get all of the records from a table where the `ExpiryDate` field is exactly one month away.

The problem however is that the `ExpiryDate` is stored with the hours, minutes and seconds. How do I therefore say - Get me all of the records from my table where the ExpiryDate (dd/MM/yyyy) is one month ahead of now (dd/MM/yyyy).

This is what I have currently:

```
SELECT *    FROM dbo.Custom_MembershipTransaction mt (nolock)
WHERE       mt.ExpiryDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
AND         mt.IsComplete = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *    FROM dbo.Custom_MembershipTransaction mt (nolock)
WHERE       convert(varchar, mt.ExpiryDate, 102) = convert(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()),102)
AND         mt.IsComplete = 1;
```

Comment: I get: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: aaa "  + INTERVAL 1 MONTH " i don't think it will work in MSSQL but i can change it to DATEADD

Comment: Ah ok I see what you're doing there. I'll test it now. Thank you btw.

Comment: This approach will restrain the index to be used.

Comment: Exactly, this is the downfall

Comment: The method proposed by @Serge should work and also use the index

Answer (score 1):

You need some buffertime like

```
SELECT *    FROM dbo.Custom_MembershipTransaction mt (nolock)
WHERE       mt.ExpiryDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
AND         mt.ExpiryDate > DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
AND         mt.IsComplete = 1;
```

This will get you all recors that have an expiredate between 1 month ahead an (1 month - 1 day) ahead.

Comment: Will this ignore the hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: This would get you all the records from GetDate() + 1 Month -1 day to GetDate() + 1 Month. Use Serge's answer instead. I had forgotten the syntax, but his is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *    FROM dbo.Custom_MembershipTransaction mt (nolock)
WHERE       mt.ExpiryDate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())), 0)
AND         mt.ExpiryDate < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()) + 1), 0)
AND         mt.IsComplete = 1;
```

I didn't make operation on ExpiryDate as it might be used by an index

Comment: Will this ignore the hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Since GETDATE() will return a datetime and not a date (yyyy/mm/dd) then all the entries from that day that have the time (hh:ii:ss) smaller then the time from GETDATE() will NOT be included , am i right?

Comment: No you're not as DATEDIFF returns a int (truncation happens).
Feel free to check the output of     DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())), 0)
(which currently is : 2013-05-16 00:00:00.000

Comment: I didn't knew that . I'm not familiar with MSSQL but in Mysql the truncation doesn't happen